# Docker: where should I put container configuration and war file

Tags: docker

Recently I was trying to figure out how a docker workflow looks like.

What I thought is, devs should push images locally and in other environments servers should just directly pull that image and run it.

But I could see a lot of public images allows people to put configurations outside the container.

For example, in official [elasticsearch](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/elasticsearch) image, there is a command as follows:

`docker run -d -v "$PWD/config":/usr/share/elasticsearch/config elasticsearch`

So what is the point of putting configuration outside the container instead of running local containers quickly?

My argument is

1. if I put configuration inside a custom image, in testing environment or production, the server just need to pull that same image which is already built.
2. if I put configuration outside the image, in other environments, there will be another process to get that configuration from somewhere. Sure we could use `git` to source control that, but is this a tedious and useless effort to manage it? And installing third party libraries is also required.

Further question:

Should I put the application file (for example, war file) inside web server container or outside it?

Comment: You should read this: http://12factor.net/config

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly thanks. Yes, that was part of what we did in the past. But I prefer to still leave some properties in configuration files, since it is easy to tune the application configs.

Comment: Docker doesn't stop you from doing that. Most good public images however are going to want to be as flexible as possible and that means using environment variables for configuration.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly yeah, you're right. After posting this question, I think I prefer to build custom images and use `docker -e` to inject secret properties. And for war file, maybe it is better to put it inside a _warfile data container_, it will decouple war from a specific web server. But either way should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing **development**, configuration files may change often; so rather than keep rebuilding the containers, you may use a **volume** instead.

If you are in **production** and need dozens or hundreds of the same container, all with slightly different configuration files, it is easy to have **one** single image and have diverse configuration files living outside (e.g. use consul, etcd, zookeeper, ... or `VOLUME`).

Comment: Yes, I totally understand that. But the world could be such wonderful if I could just do `docker run` in other environments. I guess it really depends on how often the image changes. If configuration varies among some environments, then you have to extract configuration files out from images.